# Best way to upload /sync app/game data to server. (Android Studio)

Tags: android

i have created a android app with sqllite database/android studio.its like a game.i want to upload users high score details to somewhere so users can see who is the best in a app highscore table.
i already created game and sql datase.
i dont know any method to upload data.
am i want to create a server?
can i use google drive or onedrive or something?
if i can upload to data to onedrive or something,
and if i know a method to connect to it,
i can calculate other users data and make the highscore table.

thanks please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task you would need to create a server with a database holding info for all of the registered players, or if you only want to keep track of the HighScores, simply keep the top ten results. Then you would have to sync the SQLite on the device with the database on the server on every app start or exit. On start you would pull /GET/ data from the server to update your local DB, and on exit you would POST your local results to the server. Then you could chose how to implement the server whether to track all data or just check if some of the results are good enough to be in top10 and write only them.

This is a fairly trivial task.
I recommend you read about [JSON in Android](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html), [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) and get familiar with the basics of HTTP.

You could easily figure out the "server-side" of this task simply by rolling over few videos in the web. Hope I've helped.

Comment: Glad I could help, you can accept my answer if it helped you out